# Cabal: unwanted reinstallations

Tags: haskell, dependencies, dependency-management, cabal

I always have the same problem with Cabal for various packages.
(Now I installed ghc and cabal separately, but the same problem was and when I installed Haskell Platform.) For example:

```
> cabal install extra
Resolving dependencies...
In order, the following would be installed:
directory-1.2.1.0 (reinstall) changes: time-1.4.2 -> 1.5
process-1.2.1.0 (reinstall)
extra-1.0 (new package)
cabal: The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:
process-1.2.0.0
hoogle-4.2.35
haskell98-2.0.0.3
ghc-7.8.3
Cabal-1.22.0.0
    ....... and more ...
```

But! I have already installed packages directory-1.2.1.0, process-1.2.1.0
Why cabal wants to reinstall if the plurality of packets to be broken?

```
    > ghc-pkg list process
    d:/prog/ghc-7.8.3\lib\package.conf.d:
        process-1.2.0.0

    C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\ghc\i386-mingw32-7.8.3\package.conf.d:
        process-1.2.1.0

    > ghc-pkg list directory
    d:/prog/ghc-7.8.3\lib\package.conf.d:
        directory-1.2.1.0

C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\ghc\i386-mingw32-7.8.3\package.conf.d:
    (no packages)
```

I can not remove the process-1.2.0.0. On it depends set of packages (installed with ghc-7.8.3).
And other versions of directory-1.2.1.0 does not exist at all.

Do everytime install all over again, starting with the Haskell Platform?

Please excuse me for my bad English. This is not my native language.

Comment: Welcome to cabal hell.  The reason why it wants to reinstall `process` is because one of _its_ dependencies has a new version, and so the binaries are compatible.  Have you tried using cabal sandboxes?  These were introduced a couple versions ago to provide project-specific environments.  You can still end up with cabal hell, it's just more difficult.

Comment: Cabal hell indeed. Short of reinstalling everything, you can try to fix things - this case seems to be straightforward. First, unregister `process-1.2.1.0`. If it breaks things, unregister them, and reinstall them, *but with the constraint* `--constraint="process==1.2.1.0"`. This will ensure that you don't duplicate `process`. If cabal finds no way to build one of your packages w/o updating process, you use a sandbox or install ghc and the package versions you need (not HP).